# Valor indefinido após consulta ao banco

Tags: node.js

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
var
    async = require('async'),
    pgPromise = require('../utils/pgPromise');

function anyFunction() {
    var tripItem = [];
    var tripStartEndTripItem = [];
    var tripStartEnd = [1,2,3];
    async.series({
        getIdDriver: function (callback) {
            callback(null, 'ok');
        },

        getFinishedTripsLogisticProvider: function (callback) {
            callback(null, 'ok');
        },

        getTrip: function (callback) {
            callback(null, 'ok');
        },

        getTripItem: function (callback) {
            var query = "select json_build_object ('trip_item', ti.*) from trip_item ti where ti_trip_id = ($1)";

            tripStartEnd.forEach(function(x) {
                pgPromise.db.any(query, [x.json_build_object.trip.tr_id])
                    .then(function(result) {
                       for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                            tripItem[i] = result[i].json_build_object.trip_item;
                        }

                        trip.trip_item = tripItem;

                        tripStartEndTripItem.push(trip);

                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        callback(error, null);
                    })
            });

            callback(null, tripStartEndTripItem);
       }

    }, function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error', err);
        } else {
            console.log(results);
        }
    });
}
```

O problema é quando atribuo o resultado (que está na variável `result`) da consulta ao banco a variável `tripItem`. Quando tento imprimir o resultado na tela após a iteração do array `tripStartEnd`, ele resulta como um valor `undefined`. Provavelmente ele imprime no console antes de terminar a consulta. O que eu poderia fazer para que no momento do `console.log(tripItem);`, esteja o valor da consulta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que precisas de usar o `async.compose` para o que precisas pois o series não troca dados entre as funções, elas correm em série mas sem partilhar dados. Claro que podes recorrer a variáveis globais ou dentro do escopo partilhado, mas isso permite efeitos colaterais e deixa o código menos fiável.

Depois de teres o encadeamento a passar dados para a função seguinte podes fazer assim com Promise.All():

```
function(tripStartEnd, callback) {
    var query = "select json_build_object ('trip_item', ti.*) from trip_item ti where ti_trip_id = ($1)";
    var queries = tripStartEnd.map(x => pgPromise.db.any(query, [x.json_build_object.trip.tr_id]));
    Promise.all(queries).then(arr => {
        const tripStartEndTripItem = arr.map(res => res.json_build_object.trip_item);
        callback(null, tripStartEndTripItem);
    }).catch(callback);
}
```

desta maneira, dentro da callback final do `.compose` podes receber os dados finais da cadeia de funções.